# File Parsing where one column of an array needs to be converted to a different type

Tags: c#, file, parsing, csv

Still learning and looking for a little guidance - I've got a CSV file that I'm reading into my program using a method with two foreach loops like so:

```
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
string File = File.ReadAllText("c:\\employees.txt");

string[,] filesArray = new string[File.ReadLines("c:\\employees.txt").Count(), 4]; 

foreach (string row in rawFile.Split('\n'))
{
    foreach (string col in row.Trim().Split(','))
    {
        filesArray[i, j] = col;
        j++;
    }
    j = 0;
    i++;
}
return filesArray;
```

All well and good and I can dumbly display the text fine but the format of the CSV file is

```
Z0003, EmployeeNameHere, 00001
```

and I want to do some math and other calculations based on the values in filesArray[2, 0] and so on but I'm trying to find what would be best practice for this situation.

I can think of ways that don't seem elegant and honestly it's been a bit of a mess trying to find the exact answer to this question through Google. I don't want to pick up bad habits at such an early stage!

Comment: A nudge in the right direction: Read each row into an `Employee` object instance. That means you'll need to create an `Employee` class. After reading the file, you will have a `List<Employee>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem right now is you have the data (even though getting it is ugly), but it is all in `string`s.  No matter what you do, you will have to convert to a `decimal` or other numeric format to do math on it.

I would recommend using a library like [FileHelpers](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/) to read your CSV data into an "employee" class first.  This will give you strongly typed objects.  See the 'Quick Start Delimited' entry on the left side.  your class would look something like this:

```
[DelimitedRecord(",")]
public class Employee {
    // fields in same order as in the file
    public string EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
    public int    MyNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Suggestions for current code:

1. What is `rawFile` ?? you get the lines using ReadAllLines()
2. Follow .NET naming guidelines.  `var file = ...` not `var File =`
3. Don't use the same name as common .Net classes (e.g. File).  Call it `fileLines`, etc
4. Don't read the file twice to get the # of lines.  use `new string[fileLines.Count, 4]`
5. You can use LINQ and calls to split easier if you don't use a `[,]` multi-dimensional array.
6. To convert between string and int, you will need `int.Parse` or `int.TryParse`
7. Add error checking to make sure your lines are the correct length, etc

Some sample code:

```
var data = fileLines.Select(line => line.Split(','))
                    .Where(arr => arr.Length == 4) // should have 4 fields
                    .ToArray();

var xxxx = data[0][1]; // should be "EmployeeNameHere"

// this assumes your data is ALL valid
var numbers = data.Select(x => int.Parse(x[2])).ToList();
var sum = numbers.Sum();

// there is no "pretty" way to do TryParse
var numbers = new List<int>();
foreach(var arr in data) {
    int temp = 0;
    if (int.TryParse(arr[2], out temp)) { 
         numbers.Add(temp);
    }
}
```